# Trying to rig iris' of pokemon models, however, I am stumped as to how to do such

Tags: modeling, texturing, rigging, uv-image-editor

I am still new to Blender, and have been learning areas that relate to what I am interested in. I recently learned how to make, and rig eyes because I don't want to deal with the trial and error madness that is Source eyes. I followed this guide to help me with learning how to make and rig eyes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zX5t3IZdtb8&list=LLjtd0pcB2PhTbK7C2kFxpTA&index=6&t=0s

Here is how things are looking now. This is the Pokekid Girl from Pokemon Sword and Shield. As you can see, her irises are not separate from the png image.

[image]

I tried to remove the background in paint.net and then add the texture again, and the result is... well, you can see on eyeball_L in the photo below...

[image]

After that unsuccessful attempt, I used the texture I had for the eyes in photo 1 again, and went into the object constant menu to attach the track to modifier like in the video, however, we have a problem, Houston! [image]

Not only are the eyes moved to the wrong place, when I move the armature, it moves the entire eye, not the iris. Again, I want to move the iris instead of the entire eye. If anyone has a discord account and would like to screen share to help me out in real time, my discord is Sonario648#7356

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Definitely share your file, if you can. This site isn't just about getting help, but also creating a repository of knowledge so that others can get help too.

Comment: @moonboots I would, but for some reason, I'm worried about copyright now. Even though I highly doubt Nintendo or anyone else actually really cares considering modelsresource is still up despite all those models ripped from video games

Comment: you can destroy a part of the file to make it unusable  ;)